# android - Disable the ability to drag down the notification bar

Tags: android

I am doing an android applicaiton and I know its possible to show or hide the notification bar.

but is there a way to show it but Disable the ability to drag it down?

Thanks

Comment: For me I need this in an embedded solution, so it is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think thats not possible, but you achieve something similar makin your activity FullScreen.

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Jorgesys

Comment: this code is for hiding the status bar. I am looking for a way to show it and not let the user drag it down.

Comment: well in that case, mbaird has the reason.

Comment: Just want to clarify that as far as I know its not possible, and this is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);


Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

if(!hasFocus) {
Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
}
}
```

Comment: its would be nice if you could explain what this code what doing as well :)

Comment: Sure! 
So this method is a system method same as onPause, onStart etc..
This method checks If the app lost the focus, if yes it will send an intent to the system to close any dialog above your application :)