# Disable the android notification bar

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

i just want to know how can i disable the notification bar in my mobile without making my activity fullscreen?

Im doing kind of a lockscreen and i dont want the user can drag down the notification bar.

Comment: check: [android - Disable the ability to drag down the notification bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600622/android-disable-the-ability-to-drag-down-the-notification-bar)

Comment: according to this link (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/GIq2Lao9jX4) - it is **not possible**.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in to your  AndroidManifest.xml

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Comment: Read question carefully. He dont want to **Hide** it but **Disable**

Comment: thank you, but what Paresh Mayani says is right, i want to disable the android notification bar so the user can¿t interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

public static void CancelNotification(Context ctx, int notifyId) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
    nMgr.cancel(notifyId);
}

Comment: Why are you posting brand new answers?

Comment: thank you, but when is this method invoked? or i have to invoke it manually?? if so, in which part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what you need.  It invovles creating a transparent window overlapping the status bar and thereby intercepting all touch events to it.

You'll still keep the status bar, the user just won't be able to activate it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630993/455886